# Como armazenar dados de formulário em 2 bancos diferentes?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um formulário que os dados precisam ser salvos em um banco local e em outro banco em um servidor.

Tem alguma forma de fazer isso sem duplicar os "insert" do código?
No arquivo de conexão configurei as 2 conexões, porém só insere no localhost.

```
    $host = '***';
    $user= '***';
    $pass = '***';
    $db= '***';
    $con=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

    $host2='localhost';
    $user2='***';
    $pass2='***';
    $con2=mysqli_connect($host2, $user2, $pass2, $db);
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro no insert de `$con2` ?

Comment: Você também pode configurar uma replicação entre os bancos. Assim você trabalho com apenas um banco e as alterações serão refletidas para o outro automaticamente.

Comment: @rray não parece nenhum erro

Comment: @Earendul nesse caso, isso não é viável.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A única maneira que eu vejo é assim:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO TABELA (CAMPO_1, CAMPO_2) VALUES (VALOR_1, VALOR_2)";
mysqli_query($con, $insert);
mysqli_query($con2, $insert);
```

Comment: Valeu!! não tinha pensado dessa maneira!

Answer (score 5):

```
class databaseConfig{

    var $default = array(
        'host'          => '127.0.0.1',
        'login'         => 'root',
        'password'      => '',
        'database'      => 'local',
    );

    var $server = array(
        'host'          => '192.168.100.101',
        'login'         => 'root',
        'password'      => '',
        'database'      => 'server',
    );
}

class SimpleMySqlConnect{

    private $config = array();
    private $connections = array();

    function __construct(){
        if(class_exists("databaseConfig")){
            $this->config = new databaseConfig();
        }

        $connections = get_object_vars($_this->config);
        foreach($connections as $name => $config){
            $this->connections[$name] = new mysqli($config['host'], $config['login'], $config['password'], $config['database']);
        }
    }

    function getConnection($name){
        if(in_array($name, $this->connections)){
            return $this->connections[$name];
        }
    }

    function getConnections(){
        return $this->connections;
    }
}

...

$query = "INSERT INTO myCity (Name, CountryCode, District) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$simpleMySql = new SimpleMySqlConnect();
$connections = $simpleMySql->getConnections();
foreach ($connections as $name => $mySqlClass){

    $stmt = $mySqlClass->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $val1, $val2, $val3);

    $val1 = 'Stuttgart';
    $val2 = 'DEU';
    $val3 = 'Baden-Wuerttemberg';

    $stmt->execute();
}

...
```

#### Referencia

[PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

#### Obs

Não consegui testar, não tenho Mysql neste computador, se alguém achar algum erro e quiser ajustar. Por favor o faça.